# linking process is getting error "lld-link: error: Output data is larger than 4 GiB. File size 4,339,482,624 too large for current PDB page size 4096"

Tags: build, llvm, chromium, pdb-files, brave

I am building brave browser using brave-core v1.48.8 from GitHub. after cloning brave-core, I am running the following commands inside brave-core:

1. npm install // completed successfully
2. npm run init // completed successfully
3. npm run build -- debug // throwing error and terminating the build.

the cmd snip is attached below
[image shows the error thrown by Link stage during build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpqZO.png):

I searched on internet but couldn't find much except [this](https://reviews.llvm.org/D102713), but unclear about their solution implementation using link.exe instead of lld-link.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You attempted to build with Windows SDK version 10.0.20348.0. With PDBs now exceeding 4 GiBs in size, you will need to instead use SDK version 10.0.22621.0 and the debugging tools from version 10.0.22621.755 (at the time of this writing). You will also need to use Visual Studio 2022 (>=17.0.0) as well.

These requirements are provided in the *Setting up Windows* section of the *[Checking out and Building Chromium for Windows](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#setting-up-windows)* resource, which is part of the required steps/reading for building brave-core.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Earlier I was using SDK version 10.0.22621.0 as per chromium documentation, but during build, it popped error to install SDK version 10.0.20348.0. so, I had to install SDK version 10.0.20348.0, hence SDK error resolved but now I am facing PDB size error.